Prevent Buffer Overflow/Underflow Access Algorithm
Consider a continuous data stream (e.g., a sequence of integers) that arrives over time in variable-sized chunks. Each incoming chunk has a length denoted by $n_p$, which varies between arrivals. These chunks are stored sequentially in a buffer with a maximum capacity of $N$. A separate consumer process retrieves and processes chunks of data from this buffer, also in variable-sized chunks of length $n_c$, which vary between retrievals.
The buffer operates as a first-in-first-out (FIFO) queue. When data is consumed, the oldest  elements are removed from the buffer, effectively "popping" them.
Since $n_p$ and $n_c$ vary over time, the buffer is subject to the following risks:

Overflow: If the buffer length exceeds $N$ or $n_p > n_c$ over time, resulting in data loss or write errors.

Underflow: If the buffer becomes empty or $n_p < n_c$, leaving no data for the consumer to retrieve.


To manage these risks, we need an algorithm that dynamically adjusts the production delay $dt_p$ (interval between data writes to the buffer) and consumption delay $dt_c$ (interval between data reads from the buffer) based on the current state of the buffer.
Assume the following functions are available for interacting with the buffer:

get_current_ns(): Returns the current timestamp in nanoseconds.

get_buffer_length(): Returns the current length of data in the buffer.

pop_data_stream(n_c): Retrieves and removes the oldest $n_c$ elements from the buffer.

extend_data_stream(n_p): Appends $n_p$ elements to the buffer.


Each function runs in an infinite loop, either consuming or producing data indefinitely. The algorithm must ensure that the buffer maintains an optimal balance between real-time access (low latency) and stability (avoiding overflow or underflow).
The goals are:

Primary Objective: Achieve near real-time processing without risking underflow (optimal solution).

Secondary Objective: Knowing the average value of occurrences of buffer overflow/underflow hit during adjustment, and its deviation, over time.


To address these objectives, the algorithm should dynamically adjust  and  based on the buffer’s current length, thereby optimizing the delays in producing or consuming data.
Conditions

Tolerance of Intermittent Events: Occasional overflows or underflows are acceptable as long as they do not occur repeatedly within a short time interval $\Delta t$.

Immutable Chunk Sizes: The chunk sizes $n_p$ and $n_c$ are not tunable, but the delays $dt_p$ and $dt_c$ are adjustable during runtime.

Expected Solution: A solution that minimizes underflow occurrences with low average latency.


Consider the following cases for access control:

Producer-Only Access: Only data can be produced into the buffer (no consumption allowed due to consumed by other system).

Consumer-Only Access: Only data can be consumed from the buffer (no production allowed due to produced by other system).

Full Access: Both production and consumption are permitted.


So, there are three algorithms expected.
Here is the assertions of algorithm input-output pairs. Define the input-output pairs:

Input: Initial values of $dt_p$ and $dt_c$, etc.

Output: Adjusted values of $dt_p$ and $dt_c$.


Given an initial configuration, the algorithm should determine the optimal values of $dt_p$ and $dt_c$ at runtime.
The behavior of the buffer is influenced by varying  and  values, making this a stochastic problem with aspects of control theory for regulating system stability in real-time. While algorithmic, it may require probabilistic modeling for optimal performance.

Please check the wording This get_data_stream(n_c) function runs indefinitely within an infinite loop, continuously consuming chunks from the buffer. - I read once called, it never returns. Where can a delay be specified, and how could a non-zero delay be of advantage? How could $n_c > 1$ help?

get_data_stream(n_c) might be underflow during call, but might be overflow when it's not called for a long time. It returns chunk of earlier data from buffer. Delay can be specified in non-blocking approach using get_current_ns(). $n_c$ and $n_p$ always greater than zero.

Algorithm for what entity?  Do you control the consumer?  Do you control the producer?  Can we choose an appropriate algorithm for both the consumer and producer?

Algorithm for what entity?, I'm not sure I understand, but it's about buffer underflow/overflow prevention from arbitrary incoming/retrieval length. For the control, there are three cases like I mentioned above. Regardless the cases, still, we are not allowed to set $n_c$ and $n_p$ due to nature of system. But non-blocking delay prevention is.

@D.W. Not sure what does it mean by appropriate algorithm, but if you need auxiliary variables for the algorithm, sure.

I don't understand what you mean by "an algorithm".  An algorithm for what?  What are the input to the algorithm, and what are the outputs? There are apparently two entities: a consumer, and a producer.  Are we designing an algorithm for the consumer to run?  For the producer to run?  Something else?  I can't understand the question.  I'm not asking about auxiliary variables.

Input: produce_interval or consume_interval, Output: produce_interval or consume_interval (since it runs indefinetely)

So, both input and output are same variable, but initialization known at start while optimal value will be known in runtime.

@D.W. Yes, there are three possibilities what programmer can do. Case where programmer is only allowed to call the pop function, case where programmer is only allowed to extend the new data (call extend function), and both are allowed. So, I'm looking for three pseudocodes.

Is there a way for any of the three process types to know the value of $N$?

Yes, it is. Since $N$ is constant, so it's known at first.

With avoidance of underflows and overflows the single goal, for the third case just set the delays to infinite and delay:
No underflows, no overflows, and no variance.

So, what is the formula of $dt_p$ and $dt_c$ over time, or limit to infinifty?
